# Tabs being outputted with cakephp?

Tags: php, cakephp

I've developed a web application with cakephp locally in Windows XP with xampp and everything worked just fine. Today I deployed it to a CentOS and an Ubuntu Server and with both I had a problem.
What's happening is that an Tab space is being outputed together with my information. Let's say I make an ajax call that is supposed to return `OK`, what's being returned is `" OK"`, more exactly `(0x09)OK`

I don't really know where this tab is coming from.
I've reduced my code to the maximum and still I get it.

Controller

```
public function sendcomment() {
        $this->layout = 'ajax';
        $this->set('ret', 'OK');
    }
```

View

```
<?php echo $ret; ?>
```

Even when i don't use the view file and output info directly on the layout, the tab is still there:

Controller

```
public function sendcomment() {
        $this->layout = 'testlayout';
    }
```

testlayout.ctp

```
OK
```

This is happening to all actions, no matter what the layout is.

Does anybody went through this and know what may be happening?
All my files are encoded in UTF-8 Without BOM and they work just fine thorough XAMPP on Windows.

--Edit:

Alright, some said it's a config problem, I really don't know.
However, trying to find where's the 'tab' coming from, I started putting echoes on the core files and moving forward and forward until I finally get to where the tab is.
As of index.php from the cake webroot, if I place `echo 'a'` before the `dispatch()` method, my output is `a(0x09)OK`. So the tab is indeed coming from cake.

Now here's the problem, looking at the results of several tests I finally got stuck and it has lead me to nothing.

Right now I'm on `(CakeRoot)/lib/Cake/Routing/Dispatcher.php`. Here we have the following method:

```
protected function _loadController($request) {
    $pluginName = $pluginPath = $controller = null;
    if (!empty($request->params['plugin'])) {
        $pluginName = $controller = Inflector::camelize($request->params['plugin']);
        $pluginPath = $pluginName . '.';
    }
    if (!empty($request->params['controller'])) {
        $controller = Inflector::camelize($request->params['controller']);
    }
    if ($pluginPath . $controller) {
        $class = $controller . 'Controller';
        App::uses('AppController', 'Controller');
        App::uses($pluginName . 'AppController', $pluginPath . 'Controller');
        App::uses($class, $pluginPath . 'Controller');
        if (class_exists($class)) {
            return $class;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

I'm exactly at this part:

```
    App::uses($class, $pluginPath . 'Controller');
    if (class_exists($class)) {
        return $class;
    }
```

Now here are the tests, if i put an `echo` right before the if, like this:

```
    App::uses($class, $pluginPath . 'Controller');
    echo 'a';
    if (class_exists($class)) {
        return $class;
    }
```

My output will be `a(0x09)OK`.
However if i put my echo right inside the if like this:

```
    App::uses($class, $pluginPath . 'Controller');
    if (class_exists($class)) {
        echo 'a';
        return $class;
    }
```

My output is gonna be `(0x09)aOK`.
The only thing that comes to my mind is that `class_exists()` is echoeing the tab. But that just doesn't make any sense.
For testing purposes i made this:

```
    App::uses($class, $pluginPath . 'Controller');
    if (TRUE) {
        return $class;
    }
```

Still the tab is being outputed. Even worse, if I do an `if == TRUE` like this, no matter if the echo "a" is before the if or right inside the if, the ouput will always be `a(0x09)OK`.

What is going on here?

Comment: The only includes happening are from CakePHP Core. The tab show up no matter what it's the controller, action, layout or view. The weird thing is that the app runs just fine in Windows. I'll take a look at debug kit to see if i can find what's causing this.

Comment: just go with `echo 'OK'; die;` never failed me!

Comment: @UnamataSanatarai Why? The tab is actually being outputed before.

Comment: If you `die` a `OK` then it will skip all layout and other unneccessary files. **BUT** on the second thought, are you sure you're uploading files in binary mode? Might be that your main `index.php` file is corrupted...

Comment: @UnamataSanatarai Alright, i got it. I'm definitely using binary. I will try uploading it again in a few minutes. However i did a few tests and posted here. Would you mind taking a look?

Comment: @Sonar Quite quirky i do say. Might be that whatever the class is being checked for existence, has a `(tab)<?php ` or `?>(tab)`. Tough to tell. Try echoing the class that causes the tab, open the file and see(?) ([class_exists()](http://php.net/manual/pl/function.class-exists.php) automatically calls for autoload)

Comment: @UnamataSanatarai _on the second thought, are you sure you're uploading files in binary mode?_ uploading in ascii mode is not going to magically insert a tab character somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

> So the tab is indeed coming from cake.

This is an incorrect conclusion.

### You almost have it

Paraphrasing your code:

```
App::uses($class, $pluginPath . 'Controller');
echo "before";
if (class_exists($class)) {
    echo 'after';
    return $class;
}
```

Outputs: `before(0x09)after`

There is no great mystery here. Used in this way, [class_exists](http://php.net/manual/es/function.class-exists.php) will autoload classes - i.e. include them, and any immediate class dependencies (as they will also invoke the class loading). Therefore there is a very short list of places it can come from:

- Controller/`$class`Controller.php
- Plugin/Foo/Controller/FooAppController.php (if it's a plugin controller)
- Controller/AppController.php (if it exists)

One of these files has leading or trailing whitespace - simply find it and remove it.

### Use the tools at your disposal

You do not need to guess what file is the problem, there are many, many tools which will tell you which file is the culprit. One such tool is in the [debug kit plugin](https://github.com/cakephp/debug_kit), e.g.:

```
-> Console/cake DebugKit.whitespace

Welcome to CakePHP v2.3.0-RC2 Console
---------------------------------------------------------------
App : app
Path: /path/to/app/
---------------------------------------------------------------
Checking *.php in /path/to/app/
!!!contains trailing whitespaces: /app/Controller/AppController.php
```